# Корректна ли такая запись?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, придаточное-предложение

Известно, что, если хочется употребить тире вместо двух запятых, то можно записать так:

*Это, конечно, всë хорошо, но если мы не поторопимся — мы можем опоздать*.

Тире после *поторопимся* заменяет две запятые: после *но* и после *поторопимся*:

*Это, конечно, всë хорошо, но, если мы не поторопимся, мы опоздаем*.

А такая запись корректна, где и обособляется придаточное, и стоит тире из-за паузы?

`Это, конечно, всë хорошо, но, если мы не поторопимся, — мы опоздаем.`

Две запятые обособляют придаточное, а тире стоит ввиду паузы. Так корректно?

Comment: А зачем повторяется местоимение "мы"? Можно без повтора?   Предложение звучит неестественно. Лучше так: ... но, если  не поторопимся, то опоздаем.

Comment: @Sharon Нет, «то» добавлять не надо! Иначе запятой перед _если_ не получится.

Comment: Вместо "то" можно поставить тире.  В разговорной речи очень важна естественность.  Пишите так, как говорите.

Comment: @Sharon Дело не в повторении местоимения. Дело в том, чтобы узнать, корректна ли такая запись. В вопросе только корректность мне нужна! (Не со злостью «!» стоит, если что.)

Comment: Максим, да ладно, не берите в голову, это ведь мое личное понимание и пожелание.  Корректным должно быть все)  Давайте подождем ответов.

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо. А вы не знаете точного ответа?

Comment: Да знаю я... Но я блоками все решаю, а никто в их строну даже смотреть не хочет Интересно, что другие скажут, а я, может, потом добавлю.

Comment: @Sharon Ладненько. Кстати, а почему вы перестали предложения запятой разделять, ставя после запятой заглавную букву?))

Comment: А зачем лишние знаки?   Это NEW))  И так понятно, что там точка, разве нет? Пробел, прописная буква, куда больше-то? Кстати, а  вы тоже грифом-орлом стали, так надо понимать? Никуда от этих редакторов не скроешься.  Комментарии и те проверяют)

Comment: Не, я в чат не хочу, да вообще ухожу)  До встречи.

Comment: @Sharon Как понять грифом-орлом? Просто вы вместо точки запятую раньше ставили, а прописную букву сохраняли)) А редактор комментариев один был — oleedd. Только он пропал куда-то.

Comment: Чат случайно призвал, извините.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая — не «ням».

> Это, конечно, всë хорошо, но, если мы не поторопимся — мы опоздаем.

Либо:

> Это, конечно, всë хорошо, но, если мы не поторопимся, мы опоздаем. (Нет паузы.)

Answer (score 0):

Мой варант (решение методом блоков):

*Это, конечно, всë хорошо, // **но если мы не поторопимся**  — мы опоздаем.*

**Три** предикативные основы, **граница блоков** перед союзом НО.

Вторая часть: ***Но если мы не поторопимся**  — мы опоздаем.*

БСП, условно-следственные отношения, союз ***НО*** относится к придаточному предложению и примыкает к союзу ***ЕСЛИ***.  Ставится **разделительное тире**.

Количество знаков **минимальное,** при этом их достаточно для **однозначного** понимания смысла.

Comment: Это понятно, но меня интересует, корректна ли запись выше. Меея не интересует, как правильно, мне нужно корректность той записи знать.

Comment: Это, конечно, всë хорошо, но, если мы не поторопимся, — мы опоздаем. Дополнительное тире вряд ли можно объяснить.  ПАУЗОЙ можно объяснить замену знака. Достаточно вспомнить, как Розенталь объяснял дополнительный знак  в теме вводных слов, пункт 10 (2), про интонацию он ничего не говорит. А часто ли Лопатин ставит. доп. знаки?  Он скорее будет говорить о едином знаке. В общем, вписаться в правовое поле с доп. знаком с таким объяснением сложно.

Comment: Максим,  вы стали использовать инверсию в обычной речи, а почему?)  Стилизация?

Comment: Так корректны две дополнительные запятые или нет?

Comment: Нет, доп. тире нельзя объяснить паузой.

Comment: Тире нельзя объяснить из-за запятых?

Comment: Да, ставьте одни запятые, их много получится.  Но ничего...  Но Лопатин так бы не стал делать, да и Розенталь тоже.

Comment: А если тире хочу оставить, запятые обязательно убирать, верно?

Comment: Верхняя запись корректна.  Ее по Лопатину можно объяснить.  И так пользователи пишут по слуху, без правил.